# How to add a embed image to but not attach the image in the mail?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having problem to add a image in my mail body. All ways that I uses to add a image in my php body it attach the image and i don't want it happen. I want only embed it to the mail body.

That's my mail content:

[image]

My first way: (using a phpMailer function)

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("img/LafProject.png", "LafProject", "LafProject.png");
$content = '<img src="cid:LafProject" />';
```

Thats's what happen when I try to use the code above:

[image]

(A attached file - i don't know how to remove it)

My second way: (using base64_encode in the image)

```
$content = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(get_file_contents("img/LafProject.png")) . '" />';
```

Thats's what happen when I try to use the code above:

[image]

(The same as the first way but with another filename attached)

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing out one basic thing: embedded images are also attachments. Whether they are also *displayed* as attachments depends on the implementation of your email client. The only way to avoid that is to use images that are not attachments at all, that is, that they are linked via external URLs. Unfortunately this often means that images will not be shown at all as most email client apps default to not displaying images.

The best way to handle *that* is to make sure that your layout look and works well enough both with and without images, so take advantage of alt attributes in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Change contentDisposition from 'attachment' to 'inline'